# Deploy To Digital Ocean With Shell Script And GIt Hooks Error

Tags: git, shell, githooks, digital-ocean

I have my Droplet in DigitalOcean in `/var/www/ html`. Then I made a Git Hook with the following information

```
#!/bin/sh
git push origin master
ssh root@130.122.12.112 'bash -s' < deploy.sh
```

This Git Hook called post-commit call the following Shell Script

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~
cd /var/www/html/val4505Ecoopsos
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:epjuan21/val4505Ecoopsos.git
git pull origin master
```

This is run after a commit

Then get this error

```
:No such file or directory
:No such file or directoryhtml/val4505Ecoopsos
is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings in it. Run `dos2unix` or similar on the script and see if that fixes the problem. See the `Before asking about problematic code` section of the [tag:bash] tag's [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) page.

Comment: Thanks!
I am running the script from Git Bash.The problem follows.

Comment: .... I'm not sure how that information is relevant.

Comment: I ran 'dos2unix' to deploy.sh and it worked. Thanks!